# CSS Works Fine when Running React App Locally, but when run on Server doesn't format anything

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

So I have a react app that runs totally fine when I run it locally with "npm start". All of my CSS formats correctly in the App and it looks great. However, when deployed to a server, it's as if the CSS files don't exist anymore and nothing gets formatted. I really have no idea where to look. Does anyone have any suggestions or could point me in the direction of things to try?

Structure Locally vs On Server:
[image]

Code for importing CSS (do the same method of importing throughout the whole project):
[image]

Comment: is your css be saved under src folder?

Comment: @sillyknight02 yep they are all saved under the src folder

Comment: could u show the code how you import the files and how you project files structure looks like in the server?

Comment: @sillyknight02 wanted to see if maybe you had any more insight on this? Still no luck on my end figuring this out

Comment: to be honest. in your screen shot everything looks fine to me. but have you try to use css in some other way. some work around might be gonna work out. 

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

Comment: the way you import css might have some global style conflict issue, but that doesn't explain no style apply at all in the server side. So... I guess import all css to .moudle.css worth a try

Comment: and in this way you could get style file as an instance variable. worst case you can log styles to see what's in there and so you know is those files import success or not

Comment: Most likely the issue is the file route changed in the server side, but I have never had that issue before